# Dynamic row height for table

Tags: reporting-services, row, reporting

Using Reporting Services I need to make a table where I can set the row height dynamically depending on the length of the text in the cell, so when I export in Excel the height of the row will expand accordingly to a size that can be printed out without hiding any information It is in that row. I noticed that there is a problem with exporting in Excel, and that the propriety 'CanGrow' is not really working to expand the row height as it should.

So, there is a way I can set a height for every table row, or a method to make Excel export with a correct height every row depending on the length of the text in the cell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code. I have used this code to set the height of row according to length of text:

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{   
    float a = 54.0f * [[yourArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row - 1] length]/25.0f;

    return a;
}
```